# String input in C issue

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to assign two strings in a string array but the compiler won't let me do it

```
typedef char string[20];
    string dizionario[2];

    dizionario[0] = "ergbeciao";
    dizionario[1] = "ciaozio";
```

Comment: You need to use [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

Comment: ok, but why doesn't my compiler accepts it this way?

Comment: OT, but `typedef char string[20];` is a very bad idea, it might make you believe that it magically creates a real string type, but it doesn't, it only adds confusion.

Comment: Post would be more useful if the error message that caused "won't let me do it" was included.  Searches could find this post.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
string dictionary[2] = {"Item1", "Item2"}
```

Comment: Yh just updated my answer @MichaelWalz

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array variable while declaring. In your program you are using double dimmesion of char array.I hope that u will understand and it will work

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
    typedef char string[20];
    int i;
    string dizionario[2]={ "ergbeciao", "ciaozio"};
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
      { 
        printf("\nSting i :%s",i,dizionario[i]);
      }
  }
```

Output

String 0 : ergbeciao
String 1 : ciaozio

Answer (score 1):

Your code could work if you changed the definition of `string` to something more useful:

```
typedef const char *string;

int main() {
    string dizionario[2];

    dizionario[0] = "ergbeciao";
    dizionario[1] = "ciaozio";
}
```

Note that literal strings (`"ergbeciao"`) are **immutable**.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `=` operator to copy the *contents* of one string (or any array type) to another; you must use the `strcpy` library function instead:

```
strcpy(dizionario[0], "ergbeciao");
strcpy(dizionario[1], "ciaozio");
```

This is a function of how C treats array expressions.

First and most importantly, an array expression may not be the target of an assignment (it is not a modifiable lvalue).  `dizionario[0]` and `dizionario[1]` are array expressions of type `char [20]`; by this simple virtue, they may not be the target of the `=` operator.

Secondly, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  When you write

```
dizionario[0] = "ergbeciao";
```

the compiler converts the expression `"ergbeciao"` from type "10-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

You can use a string literal as an initializer in a declaration:

```
string dizionario[2] = { "ergbeciao", "ciaozio" };
```

In this case, the contents of the string literals will be copied to the array elements as you expect.  But this *only* works as part of a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not directly assign value in string by assignment operator you should have to do string operation like this `strcpy(dizionario[0] , "ergbeciao");` and `strcpy(dizionario[1] , "ciaozio");` otherwise you have to directly assign it while declare that string.

your code should be like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){

 typedef char string[20];

 string dizionario[2];

 strcpy(dizionario[0] , "ergbeciao");
 strcpy(dizionario[1] , "ciaozio");

 printf("%s\n %s\n",dizionario[0],dizionario[1]);

 }
```

your output is:

```
ergbeciao
ciaozio
```

**cheers..........**

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon what you want to accomplish.

If you want to declare and allocate two, contiguous strings of 20 characters, fixed width, there are two approaches,

```
#define STRMAX (20)
typedef char string[STRMAX+1]; //need room for null terminator
string dizionario[2] = { "ergbeciao", "ciaozio" }; //array of char[20+1]
```

or you can allocate, then assign values using strcpy,

```
string dizionario[2] = { 0 }; //empty
strcpy( dizionario[0], "ergbeciao" );
strcpy( dizionario[1], "ciaozio" );
```

However, you may want an array of pointers to strings, so define differently,

```
#define STRMAX (20)
typedef char string[STRMAX+1]; //need room for null terminator
string* dizionario[2] = { 0 }; //array of null pointers
```

Then assign the literal strings (pointers) to the pointer array,

```
dizionario[0] = "ergbeciao";
dizionario[1] = "ciaozio";
```

Or provide distinct memory using malloc,

```
dizionario[0] = malloc("ergbeciao");
dizionario[1] = malloc("ciaozio");
```

Better, provide constructor and destructor for string,

```
string*
stringNew(char* sp)
{
    char* np = malloc(STRMAX+1);
    if(!np) return np; //malloc failed
    if(sp) strcpy(np,sp); //null source pointer
    return np;
}
void
stringDel(string* sp)
{
    if(!sp) return; //avoid double free
    free(sp);
    return(sp);
}

dizionario[0] = stringNew("ergbeciao");
dizionario[1] = stringNew("ciaozio");
```